# How to add more than one number for the conditional IF on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Need to create a stimulation for my statistics class and am feeling overwhelmed with all these functions.

Question - my current coding on google sheets is
=IF(C3+D3+E3=2,RANDBETWEEN(1,5),2)

Is there any way to have more than one value as the sum of the three numbers (C3+D3+E3) as part of the condition, such as if the sum is 2 OR 3 then generate a number between 1 and 5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's tough to write and read this sort of thing because google (and most spreadsheets) use prefix notation, but this is valid:

```
=IF(OR(C3+D3+E3=2,C3+D3+E3=3),RANDBETWEEN(1,5))
```

`OR` takes a list of logical expressions and is true if any of them are true.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks!